# Web-scraping with xpathSApply. Getting xmlValue

Tags: r, web-scraping

For example, I want to extract the price(top-right) and The space(Accommodates: 2,Bathrooms: 1 etc) https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/12949270?guests=1&s=_JaPbz-J

Here is my code for price:

```
remDr$navigate(url)
doc <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
var <- remDr$findElement('id','details')

varxml <- htmlTreeParse(vartxt, useInternalNodes=T)
Price <- xpathApply(varxml,"//div[@class='book-it__price-amount h3 text-special pull-left']",xmlValue)
```

But it returns me empty list. Maybe it hapepend, beacause the class "'book-it__price-amount h3 text-special pull-left' is not the upper class? If so - how to correct that? If not, where did I make a mistake?

Comment: For example, the [Terms of Service](https://www.airbnb.com/terms?locale=en) say _" In connection with your use of the Site, Application, Services and Collective Content, you may not and you agree that you will not: (...) use manual or automated software, devices, scripts, robots, backdoors or other means or processes to access, "scrape," "crawl" or "spider" any web pages or other services contained in the Site, Application, Services or Collective Content "_. What, if they go bankrupt because of your activities??

Answer (score 0):

For me the code below works. About forbidden scraper on the web. In general if it's not allowed to use scraper you take risk if you use data for commercial purposes or you on regular bases send get requests. So depends how you are gonna use it

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

url<-getURL("https://www.airbnb.cz/rooms/12949270?guests=1&s=_JaPbz-J",ssl.verifypeer = F)
url2<-htmlParse(url)
Price <- xpathSApply(url2,"//div[@class='book-it__price-amount h3 text-special pull-left']",xmlValue)
conditions <- xpathSApply(url2,"//div[@class='col-md-6']",xmlValue)
```

Comment: Oh, I use a Little bit other approach:
Look please at my edited version of code. I use Rselenium for my scraping